# call a stored function on postgres from java

Tags: postgresql, stored-procedures, jdbc

I've created the following function in my Postgres database:

```
CREATE FUNCTION funct(arg1 type1, arg2 type2, ...) RETURNS void AS $$
BEGIN
--insert passed args in some tables
END
```

How can I call this function from java and pass args properly?

Comment: Simply run `select funct(1, 2, 3)`

Answer (score 3):

Provided you understand how to use JDBC to talk to postgres (if not [this tutorial](http://zetcode.com/db/postgresqljavatutorial/) should get you up to speed), then this [JDBC page](http://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/head/callproc.html) shows how to call stored functions:

For example:

```
// Setup function to call.
Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
stmt.execute("CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION refcursorfunc() RETURNS refcursor AS '"
        + " DECLARE "
        + "    mycurs refcursor; "
        + " BEGIN "
        + "    OPEN mycurs FOR SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2; "
        + "    RETURN mycurs; "
        + " END;' language plpgsql");
stmt.close();

// We must be inside a transaction for cursors to work.
conn.setAutoCommit(false);

// Procedure call.
CallableStatement proc = conn.prepareCall("{ ? = call refcursorfunc() }");
proc.registerOutParameter(1, Types.OTHER);
proc.execute();
ResultSet results = (ResultSet) proc.getObject(1);
while (results.next()) {
    // do something with the results...
}
results.close();
proc.close();
```

There are other kinds of stored function discussed on the latter link also.

Comment: i've already read that tutorial but:
-i've declared the function inside my database, and i need only to call from java client
-my function doesn't return any cursor, just void

Answer (score 2):

Calling postgresql function/stored procedure is little bit different than normal Sql call. Some time back I was also faced similar problem,i searched a lot, then i found solution. below I am sharing the solution.

Below is the postgresql function

```
Create or Replace Function myfunction(id integer) Returns Table(empid integer,empname charactervarying) AS
$BODY$
DECLARE
var_r record;

BEGIN
FOR var_r IN(
select * from emp where empno=id
)

LOOP
empid:=var_r.empno;
empname:=var_r.empname;
RETURN NEXT;
end LOOP;

END; $BODY$
LANGUAGE plsql VOLATILE
```

when we will run the query in postgresql console, it will give the result according to the records present in the table for id=5

```
select myfunction(5);
```

Now we have to write code to call this function from java. below is the code

```
public class Employee {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

    try {
    callProc();
    }Catch(SQLException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    }
    }

    public static void callProc () throws SQLException {



        Connection con=DBConnection.getConnection();
        Statement statement=con.createStatement();
    //Call to postgresql function   
        String query=" call myfunction(?)";
        CallableStatement ps=con.prepareCall(query);
        ps.setInt(1,5)  // it means we are setting value 5 at first index.
        ResultSet rs=ps.executeQuery();
        List<Emp> listOfEmp=new ArrayList<Emp>();

        while(rs.next()){

        Emp data=new Emp();
        data.setEmpno(rs.getInt("empid"));
        data.setEmpName(rs.getString("empid"));
        listOfEmp.add(data);

        }
        system.out.println("Total emp"+listOfEmp.size());
    }
}
```

In above example we have written the code to call the postgresql function from java.

for more details see this
[Postgresql Function with java](http://stuffarrow.com/how-to-call-postgresql-function-with-parameters-from-java/)

Answer (score 1):

I know this is a bit old, but I stumbled upon the same problem and found a solution myself. It was pretty straightforward, but I hope this works for future reference.

```
CallableStatement statement = connection.prepareCall(" { call function( ?, ?, ? ) } ");

statement.setInt(1, value);
statement.setInt(2, value);
statement.setInt(3, value);
statement.execute();
statement.close();
```

Notice that there isn't a `? =` before the `call` in the actuall sql code and that there is no call to `registerOutParameter` method.

Answer (score 0):

Use createNativeQuery In your transaction write this and change **myschema.mymethodThatReturnASelect**
for the scheme and the name of your function.

```
@Override
    public List<ViewFormulario> listarFormulario(Long idUsuario) {
        List<ViewFormulario> list =null;
        try {
            Query q = em.createNativeQuery("SELECT * FROM myschema.mymethodThatReturnASelect(?);");
            q.setParameter(1, idUsuario);

             List<Object[]> listObject = (List<Object[]>) q.getResultList();
            if (listObject != null && !listObject.isEmpty()) {
                list = new ArrayList<>();
                for (Object o[] : listObject) {
                    ViewFormulario c = new ViewFormulario();
                    c.setIdProyecto(o[0] != null ? Long.valueOf(o[0].toString()) : -1L);
                    c.setIdUsuario(o[1] != null ? Integer.valueOf(o[1].toString()) : -1);
                    c.setIsCreador(o[2] != null ? Boolean.valueOf(o[2].toString()) : null);
                    c.setIdPadre(o[3] != null ? Long.valueOf(o[3].toString()) : -1L);
                    c.setNombre(o[4] != null ? o[4].toString() : "");
                    c.setNombreCliente(o[5] != null ? o[5].toString() : "");
                    c.setCodigo(o[6] != null ? o[6].toString() : "");
                    c.setEstado(o[7] != null ? Long.valueOf(o[7].toString()) : -1L);
                    c.setTotalDisponible(o[8] != null ? Double.valueOf(o[8].toString()) : 0.0);
                    c.setCantidadAlmacenamiento(o[9] != null ? Double.valueOf(o[9].toString()) : 0.0);
                    c.setPorcentajeAlmacenamiento(o[10] != null ? Double.valueOf(o[10].toString()) : 0.0);
                    c.setCantidadUsuario(o[11] != null ? Long.valueOf(o[11].toString()) : 0);
                    c.setCantidadRegistros(o[12] != null ? Long.valueOf(o[12].toString()) : 0);
                    c.setMbFoto(o[13] != null ? Double.valueOf(o[13].toString()) : 0.0);
                    c.setMbVideo(o[14] != null ? Double.valueOf(o[14].toString()) : 0.0);
                    c.setMbTexto(o[15] != null ? Double.valueOf(o[15].toString()) : 0.0);
                    list.add(c);
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("listarFormulario " + e.getMessage());
        }
        return list;
  }
```